# Probability of toss of random Value X

Tags: probability

A random variable X has the probability distribution

value                1  ,       2        ,     3     ,         4

probability         0.5  ,     0.25      ,    0.125     ,   0.125

(For those of you who are interested, this is the geometric $p=0.5$ “killed” at $4$. $X$ is the number of times I toss a coin if I follow this rule: I’ll toss the coin till I get the first head, but I’ll stop after $4$ tosses even if I haven’t got a head by that time.)

Find $E(X)$; expected value and $SE(X)$; standard error of $X$?

$E(X)$ = Average = $(1*0.5)+(2*0.25)+(3*0.125+(4*0.125)=1.875$ ok

$SE(X)$=standard error of $X = SD= SQRt((1-1.875)^2 *0.5+(2-1.875)^2 *0.25+(3-1.875)^2 *0.125+(4-1.875)^2*0.125)=$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a random variable that takes values $x_1,x_2,x_3,...,x_n$ with probabilities $p_1,p_2,p_3,...,p_n$, the expected value is:

$\mu=E[X]=x_1*p_1+x_2*p_2+x_3*p_3+...+x_n*p_n$

Your solution has $1*\frac{1}{4}+2*\frac{1}{4}+3*\frac{1}{4}+4*\frac{1}{4}$. This would be correct if each of the probabilities was $\frac{1}{4}$, but that is not the case here.

The standard error is:
$\sigma=\sqrt{E[(X-\mu)^2]}=\sqrt{(x_1-\mu)^2*p_1+(x_2-\mu)^2*p_2+(x_3-\mu)^2*p_3+...+(x_n-\mu)^2*p_n}$

Your solution for the standard error does not include any probabilities (and the value of $\mu$ from the first part is incorrect).

Does this help?

Comment: Yes it clearly did help Thanks CommonersG!

Answer (score 1):

You're given a random variable $X$ with probability mass function $p_X$ given by
$$
p_X(x)=P(X=x)=
\begin{cases}
0.5 &\quad\text{if }x=1 \\
0.25 &\quad\text{if }x=2 \\
0.125 &\quad\text{if }x=3 \\
0.125 &\quad\text{if }x=4
\end{cases}
$$
Now, to calculate the expected value you use the formula for a [discrete random variable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Discrete_random_variable.2C_finite_case)
$$
{\rm E}[X]=\sum_{x}x\cdot p_X(x).
$$
Note that this is in fact a *weighted* average of the values $1,2,3,4$ weighted by the probability of $X$ taking on that specific value. This is why your formula is incorrect, it fails to take the probabilities/weights into account.

Now, to calculate the standard error, you must first calculate the variance $\mathrm{Var}(X)$ of $X$. To do this we can use the [calculation formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Definition):
$$
\mathrm{Var}(X)={\rm E}[X^2]-{\rm E}[X]^2.
$$
We already know the last term and finding ${\rm E}[X^2]$ is an easy exercise using [the law of the unconscious statistician](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician) stating that
$$
{\rm E}[X^2]=\sum_x x^2\cdot p_X(x).
$$
To find the standard error you simply take the square root of the variance.

Note that you can actually calculate the variance directly using the law of the unconscious statistician as
$$
{\rm Var}(X)={\rm E}[(X-\mu)^2]=\sum_x (x-\mu)^2\cdot p_X(x)
$$
where $\mu={\rm E}[X]$ is the expected value of $X$. Again you forgot to *weight* with the probabilities in your formula.